# When you lose a button of your shirt/coat/jeans

Tags: verbs

Imagine you are walking with your friend waiting for a meeting to get started and suddenly you come to yourself and notice that one of your shirt's / jeans'/ coat's buttons has been lost! You want to express your surprise or annoyance to your friend. What would be the best way to inform someone about it:

> 1- My shirt's button fell off. 
>   2- My shirt's button has fallen off. 
>   3- My shirt's button is missing.

Comment: This seems to be a "magic words" type question.  The simple fact is that there is not always a single best way to express something.  There could be hundreds of ways of expressing some aspect of annoyance at losing a button.  Perhaps if you indicated why you think these examples might be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way you are phrasing it, a native might say

> My shirt button has fallen off.

The possessive "**'s**" is not necessary since the button does not belong to your shirt, both belong to you.
*Shirt* is used as an adjective in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could say:

> My shirt has lost a button.

Comment: This is what I would use. Or, I might say, "I lost a button off my shirt." But the point is: When I announce that I've lost a button, the word _button_ is more likely to be an object than the subject of the sentence (as in the OP's examples).

Answer (score 1):

All of the above options are fine. My most natural way to say it would probably be something like:

> I lost a shirt-button.
>
> My jeans-button is gone.

Note that I made a compound noun of "shirt-button" and "jeans-button", specifying the type of button. I think the fact that *I* lost the button is more important in my mind, rather than using "shirt's button" to give possession of the button to the shirt. I care that *I* lost *my* button, chuckle.